# SignalR fails to send message to a group when running through LoadBalancer

Tags: signalr

In order to send SignalR message to a specific user I create a Group for each user upon connection

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    log.DebugFormat("Connected. Connection Id = {0} UserId = '{1}'", Context.ConnectionId, UserHelper.UserId);
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, UserHelper.UserId);
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

Now when a message comes in I send it a group in the following way:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<AlertsHub>();

foreach (var recipient in recipients)
{
    hubContext.Clients.Group(recipient).broadcastAlertMessage("Group", msg);
}
```

That **works fine when deployed to a server**, but for some reason not working when i access the server through our company load balancer (Citrix Netscaler SDX 11500) but eventually hitting the same sole box.

There is no issue sending messages to all clients

```
hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastAlertMessage("All", msg);
```

Also i can keep the connection IDs internally and send messages to a specific client works

```
hubContext.Clients.Client(AlertsHub.UserToConnectionIdDict["admin"]).broadcastAlertMessage("trageted client", msg);
```

Why "Group" message doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

By default, a SignalR server is only aware of and will only send messages to clients connected directly to itself. This is because each SignalR server manages its own messages using its own message bus. Without special configuration, SignalR has no way to know there are other clients connected to a different SignalR server at the same global address.

Fortunately SignalR has scaleout providers that allow you to configure all your SignalR servers in such a way that they can communicate with each other by sharing single message bus.

This "Introduction to Scaleout in SignalR" should provide you with the info you need to get SignalR working properly behind a load balancer: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr

Comment: Even though we have a loadbalancer there is only one server behind it at this point (to exactly rule out this issue). So all clients connect to the same box eventually. Also Client.All works 100% reliably, only Groups has issues

Comment: I have the same issue with Groups, sending message to groups via SQL back plane